# What does "practice" mean here?

Tags: vocabulary

Excerpted from : [link to article](http://www.ifets.info/journals/12_3/16.pdf)

I am wondering what ***practice*** could mean there:

> The field of business requires multifaceted **practices** for real-world problems as much as or more than any other field.
>   A business school expects that application skills and knowledge available to MBA graduates will be comparable to
>   the skills and knowledge possessed by business professionals. Creating learning situations where knowledge can be
>   acquired, organized, and applied, then, is a vital consideration for business educators. Case-based learning facilitates
>   learning transfer and real-world applicability, which is the main concern in the teaching philosophy of business
>   education

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sentence, *practice* is a noun, not a verb, and it means:

> **practice** (*n.*) *repeated exercise in or performance of an activity or skill so as to acquire or maintain proficiency in it*

The paragraph as a whole is meant to emphasize the importance of case-based study during business school, because business schools should demand that their students ***practice*** their decision-making skills before graduating, in order to hone them.

(In my sentence, I am using *practice* as a verb, not a noun. The two meanings are related, and are even similarly defined:

> **practice** (*v.*) *perform (an activity) or exercise (a skill) repeatedly or regularly in order to improve or maintain one's proficiency*

<sup>(defintions from : [link to dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/practice))</sup>